# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sc' with RowMatrix

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter, recommendation-engine

I'm currently using pyspark with Apache Spark (v 2.2.1). My IDE is Jupyter Notebook.
I'm trying to calculte Similarities of a row matrix. I followed this documentation : http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html?highlight=rowmatrix#pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix

My code is :

```
import pyspark
import random
from pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed import CoordinateMatrix, RowMatrix

conf = pyspark.SparkConf().setAll([('spark.executor.memory', '3g'), ('spark.executor.cores', '8'), ('spark.cores.max', '24'), ('spark.driver.memory', '9g')])
sc = pyspark.SparkContext.getOrCreate()
sc.stop()
sc = pyspark.SparkContext(appName="AugustinJob", master="spark://10.2.48.88:7077", conf=conf)
spark = SparkSession(sc)

#Similarities
rows = sc.parallelize([[1, 2], [1, 5]])
mat = RowMatrix(rows)
sims = mat.columnSimilarities()
sims.entries.first().value`
```

And I have this error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-69da006f7939> in <module>()
     13 mat = RowMatrix(rows)
     14 sims = mat.columnSimilarities()
---> 15 sims.entries.first().value

/usr/local/apache/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/rdd.py in first(self)
   1359         ValueError: RDD is empty
   1360         """
-> 1361         rs = self.take(1)
   1362         if rs:
   1363             return rs[0]

/usr/local/apache/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/rdd.py in take(self, num)
   1341 
   1342             p = range(partsScanned, min(partsScanned + numPartsToTry, totalParts))
-> 1343             res = self.context.runJob(self, takeUpToNumLeft, p)
   1344 
   1345             items += res

/usr/local/apache/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/context.py in runJob(self, rdd, partitionFunc, partitions, allowLocal)
    990         # SparkContext#runJob.
    991         mappedRDD = rdd.mapPartitions(partitionFunc)
--> 992         port = self._jvm.PythonRDD.runJob(self._jsc.sc(), mappedRDD._jrdd, partitions)
    993         return list(_load_from_socket(port, mappedRDD._jrdd_deserializer))
    994 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sc'
```